# Post image will not align centre or right in wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I've built a custom theme for wordpress and when the user tries to insert an image into a blog post it will not align center or right. I've inspected the individual image and there doesn't appear to be any CSS forcing this issue.
The image aligns correctly in the post editor.

The post is [here](http://chatterboxcomms.co.uk/2016/03/01/why-were-supporting-homes-for-wales/).

Can anyone identify what is causing this behavior?

Comment: `img class="float: right alignright wp-image-59 size-medium"` seems to point to the culprit. You have inline CSS in the class attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your markup is not correct:

```
class="float: right alignright wp-image-59 size-medium"
```

You **should** also specify CSS properties for default **.alignright** and **.alignleft** classes, added by WordPress on floating images **by default.**

EDIT:

You should add:

```
.alignright {
  float: right;
}

.alignleft {
  float: left;
}
```

And perhaps add some margin around, depending on the left/right image.

Comment: Apologies, that was me trying a few fixes. I've removed the additional inline CSS and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Check the other part of my comment - you don'' have alignright or alignleft   styles defined, I will edit my answer.

Comment: my pleasure, don't forget to mark my answer, all i ask in return :)